# Hashcat and naive-hashcat Kali Linux CPU/GPU driver issue

Tags: kali-linux, drivers, gpu

I am trying to run hashcat and naive-hashcat in Kali linux, but I am having problems with cpu/gpu divers.
If I run `hashcat` i get this error:

```
Device #1: Not a native Intel OpenCL runtime. Expect massive speed loss.
             You can use --force to override, but do not report related errors.
```

while if I run `naive-hashcat` I get this error:

```
* Device #1: Not a native Intel OpenCL runtime. Expect massive speed loss.
             You can use --force to override, but do not report related errors.
* Device #2: Outdated or broken Intel OpenCL runtime detected!
```

I am running Kali in a virtual machine. I have an intel 7500U CPU, its integrated GPU (HD 620) and an AMD R7-M445 dedicated GPU.
Looking in the hashcat wiki "I may have the wrong driver installed, what should I do?" makes me confused about which are the correct packages to install (Intel OpenC from apt or from intel's site, amd driver from apt or from ROCm's, and so on...).